# Ory Kratos custom UI google login session error

Tags: ory, ory-hydra

I am using ory-kratos for user management but I need my own UI, so I followed the docs

(link : https://www.ory.sh/docs/guides/bring-your-user-interface)

and configured my own ui (using this nextjs template https://github.com/ory/kratos-selfservice-ui-react-nextjs) and configured the endpoints accordingly in the ory console (in the user interface tab under the customize section).

After everything is configured, the normal username and password login flow works fine but when I added social login with google(via configuring Social Sign-in in ory console) I get an error I don't understand (something to do with session)

[image]

I have tried to temporary reset everything to it's default managed UI and there is no error meaning it works and I can login with google with it's own default managed UI.

The original default settings in kratos console for managed ui is :

```
/ui/login
/ui/registration
/ui/settings
/ui/verification
/ui/recovery
/ui/error
```

and my own setting is:

```
http://localhost:3000/login
http://localhost:3000/registration
http://localhost:3000/settings
http://localhost:3000/verification
http://localhost:3000/recovery
http://localhost:3000/error
```

of course my own ui is running locally on http://localhost:3000, but I get that error whenever I use my own settings

Am wondering what I have to implement or adjust to resolve this issue since I don't have a clear idea on why this is happening.
I have found a somewhat similar issue but still could not fully understand the meaning
(link : https://github.com/ory/kratos/discussions/2486)